# CSRF token on Laravel 5 + AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, laravel, laravel-5

There's an existing project built on Laravel 5.2.5 and angularjs 1.7.4. The are no html pages generated by laravel, only API. The project is supposed to use CSRF protection.

Angular docs say, that the [$http service will automatically set the X-XSRF-TOKEN header](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#cross-site-request-forgery-xsrf-protection).

> When performing XHR requests, the $http service reads a token from a
>   cookie (by default, XSRF-TOKEN) and sets it as an HTTP header (by
>   default X-XSRF-TOKEN).

I found that the [Laravel 5.2 docs say that it will check for the X-XSRF-TOKEN header as well](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#csrf-x-xsrf-token).

> Laravel also stores the CSRF token in a XSRF-TOKEN cookie. You can use
>   the cookie value to set the X-XSRF-TOKEN request header. Some
>   JavaScript frameworks, like Angular, do this automatically for you. It
>   is unlikely that you will need to use this value manually.

But what I get is `TokenMismatchException` error from Laravel.

Do I have to use some additional set up to implement CSRF protection here ?

Comment: Did you just upgrade your Laravel version from 5.2 to 5.7 and got this error? Or are you checking docs for a totally different version of Laravel? Also, you can check the headers on requests being made by the front end by opening developer tools (F12) and check which token is send if any token is send at all.

Comment: Sorry, I had already updated my question but somebody overwrote my edits. I use 5.2, the docs are here https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#csrf-x-xsrf-token

Comment: No worries. As far as i understand, Laravel should be storing the CSRF token in a cookie. Try inspecting the developer tools and check if any cookie with the name `CSRF-TOKEN` is set. If so, then check if the requests send from the front end includes the token in the header `X-CSRF-TOKEN`. If so, check if the token in the headers matches the token in the cookie.

Comment: Yep, I did it before asking the question :) and it's `XSRF-TOKEN` and `X-XSRF-TOKEN`, just like the docs say.  I've been testing the api with postman for about two hours, tried to add it as `_token` or `csrf_token` to my post data. I'm just wondering what is the  default set-up for laravel+angular js csrf ?

Comment: Did you verify the token being send to the back end as a header, not as a cookie? Do the tokens match (cookie and header). Does it work in postman (probably another token, so check if you have the right one)?

Comment: you will get XSRF-TOKEN and laravel_session header for every request you make (in response) with set-cookie you need to use those for token

Comment: Yes, I get XSRF-TOKEN and laravel_session in the Set-cookie header. What I did in postman: I ran my POST /login method, manually copied xsrf value from the Set-cookie header, pasted it into X-XSRF-TOKEN header value, ran POST /getList method (protected by csrf middleware). In my understanding, this is how it supposed to work between laravel and angularjs. Am I right?

Comment: yes @sr9yar....

Answer (score 0):

try add _token field to body of $http service.
example:

```
// blade template layout without jquery:
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
...
<script>
     window._token = document.querySelector("[name=csrf-token]").getAttribute("content");
</script>

// service.js
$http.post('/api/v1/user/create', {
    _token: window._token,
    fullname: 'foo',
    ...
});
```

Comment: This might work, but I **do not generate any pages with blade**, this is an important part. I can't use `csrf_token()` function. I wrote that in my question.

Comment: Oh.your app layout is not blade template.I think you should using blade template as app layout, or you can call a request for get csrf_token via an api (alway call when re open the app) :D

Comment: He should not be using Blade as the app layout... He is using AngularJS SPA as a front end. Nothing to do with Blade. It's a perfectly normal way of doing things. The fact that Laravel provides blade support out of the box does not mean you must use it.

Comment: Laravel is supposed to refresh csrf_token on every request, no ? o_0 So how can I add a separate method for csrf token then ?

Comment: you will get XSRF-TOKEN and laravel_session header for every request you make (in response) with set-cookie you need to use those for token

Comment: @Harsha Yes, right, but angular already does this, doesn't it ?